# My printers keep spinning

Tags: printing

Ok, this sounds kind of silly but every time one of the Ubuntu laptops on the network wakes up from sleep, gets booted or sometimes when USB devices are connected/disconnected all my printers go brrrrrrr.

I am guessing that they are getting some kind of signal to warm up or are otherwise pinged.

How do I make that stop?

The printers are an Epson WF-7525 and a HP Laserjet 2500N. The Ubuntu version on these machines is 20.04 or 19.10.

The printers are connected via ethernet cable and wifi. I have installed drivers for them on some of the machines but not all of them.

Comment: I honestly didn't think that this was vital info but I will edit.

Comment: Okay, added that. Done!